# Word with most 'o' characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to write a Python function that returns the word from the string with largest number of 'o' characters. For example, `get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao ooo'])` should return `['ooo']` and `get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao   oa aaaooo   aooqq aoooq'])` should return `['aaaooo', 'aoooq']`.

I tried this:

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
   k=0
   for i in range(len(words)-1):
      if words[i].count('o')>words[i-1].count('o'):
         k=words[i]
   return(k)
```

The problem is that this list consists only of 1 element – the whole string – and I don't know how to separate words in this list.

upd: actually, there was a mistake in the task: the input should be a string, not a list

Comment: Are these strings are split by `_` only?

Comment: Split the phrase using phrase.split().

Comment: `['aa ao ooo']` is a list that contains a single element (a string with spaces), so it doesn't make a lot of sense to use as input. It would make more sense to use `['aa', 'ao', 'ooo']`, or simply a string like `'aa ao ooo'` which could be turned into a list with `split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution allows multiple lines as input, because I checked that your input is a list.

```
def get_most_ooo_word(lines):
    k = -1
    most_o = []
    for line in lines:
        phrase_words = line.split()
        for word in phrase_words:
            c = word.count('o')
            if c > k:
                k = c
                most_o = [word]
            elif c == k:
                most_o.append(word)
    return most_o


print(get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao ooo']))
print(get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao oa    aaaooo aooqq aoooq']))
print(get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao ooo', 'aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq']))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for i in range(len(lines)):` in python, especially if you are not interested in the numerical values of `i`. Instead use the much nicer `for line in lines: ...`

Answer (score 13):

Here is one optimized way using `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
In [39]: def get_max_with(lst, char):
    ...:     d = defaultdict(list)
    ...:     for w in lst:
    ...:         d[w.count(char)].append(w)
    ...:     return d[max(d)]
    ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [40]: lst
Out[40]: ['aa', 'ao', 'oa', 'aaaooo', 'aooqq', 'aoooq']

In [41]: get_max_with(lst, 'o')
Out[41]: ['aaaooo', 'aoooq']
```

In case where all the items have zero occurrence of the expected char you can check the number of `max(d)` before accessing the respective value in dictionary and return whatever you want.

Comment: This is the route I'd go... (or maybe even `dict.setdefault`) - however, one thing (the OP doesn't specify - so could well not be an issue) that's worth considering is where all words have no `o`'s in them...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, that's an exception need to be handled.

Comment: These days I have been trying to read many python code of some famous packages and I have seen many implementation just like this. Nice approach

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
   words=words.split()
   k={word:word.count('o') for word in words}
   t=max(k.values())
   return [i for i in k if k[i]==t]


print(get_most_ooo_word('aa ao ooo'))
print(get_most_ooo_word('aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq'))
```

V2:For duplicate words

```
 def get_most_ooo_word(words):
       words=words.split()
       k={(i,word):word.count('o') for i,word in enumerate(words)}
       t=max(k.values())
       return [i[1] for i in k if k[i]==t]
    print(get_most_ooo_word('ooo ooo ooo')
```

V3 :For preserving order below Py3.6

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
   words=words.split()
   k=OrderedDict(((i,word),word.count('o')) for i,word in enumerate(words))
   t=max(k.values())
   return [i[1] for i in k if k[i]==t]


print(get_most_ooo_word('ooo ooo ooo'))
print(get_most_ooo_word('aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq'))
```

Comment: Looks like a decent solution now.

Comment: There's no reason to use a dict here. You can simply make it a list of tuples, and then you won't need to worry about duplicates or order.

Answer (score 2):

So basically, you need a list of words that contains the most occurrences of `o` among all.

The idea would be simple: You maintain a list of "items with the known highest value". You discard the previous list if you found an item with a higher value than the "known highest", or append it to the current list if it has exactly the same value as "known highest". Then it's not hard to come up with this code:

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
    words = words[0].split()
    most = [words[0]]
    for word in words[1:]:
        if word.count('o') > most[0].count('o'):
            most = [word]
        elif word.count('o') == most[0].count('o'):
            most.append(word)
    return most
```

Comment: `elseif` hey? :p

Comment: @JonClements Sorry I messed it up with some other languages.

Comment: @JonClements SO never disallows someone to answer a Python question right after they've done a VBScript job, right?

Answer (score 2):

A small and short code that returns a `list` with max `'o'` occuring words :

```
>>> l = [(ele, ele.count('o')) for ele in s.split(' ')]
>>> max_v = max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> [word for word, count in l if count==max_v[1]]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : s = 'aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq'
OUT : ['aaaooo', 'aoooq']

IN : s = 'aa ao ooo'
OUT : ['ooo']

IN : s = 'ooo ooo ooo'
OUT : ['ooo', 'ooo', 'ooo']
```

Comment: Might be a slight issue where the original text contains duplicated words - you'll only get one occurrence - try `'ooo ooo ooo'` as your input. (Also - the order of the words won't be preserved - whether that's important or not is another issue)

Comment: @JonClements, check now.

Comment: @JonClements Order will be preserved from py3.6 onwards

Comment: @SmartManoj that leaves a *lot* of Python versions still in the wild where that's not the case... so making that assumption right now is somewhat dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

if you call `get_most_ooo_word(['aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq'])`:

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
   k=0
   words = words[0].split(" ")
   for i in range(len(words)-1):
      if words[i].count('o')>words[i-1].count('o'):
         k=words[i]
   return(k)
```

if you call `get_most_ooo_word('aa ao oa aaaooo aooqq aoooq')`:

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):
       k=0
       words = words.split(" ")
       for i in range(len(words)-1):
          if words[i].count('o')>words[i-1].count('o'):
             k=words[i]
       return(k)
```

or combine both:

```
def get_most_ooo_word(words):

           if type(words) == list and len(words) > 0:
                 words = words[0].split()
           else:
                 words = words.split()
           k=words[0]
           for i in range(1, len(words)-1):
              if words[i].count('o')>words[i-1].count('o'):
                 k=words[i]
           return(k)
```

[image]

Comment: This won't return multiple hits, and it'll raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: see again. I edited my answer. First time I wrote answer according to your call examples where your argument 'words' were list, not string

Comment: look at outputs

Comment: Wrong answer for input `aa ao oo`. Check again (I tested it locally. Sorry for the IndexError thing - I forgot some Python).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to splitting the line is `split` - however you can change the code to do this a different way - though this might be more confusing if you're not used to comprehensions:

```
a = 'aa ao   oa aaaooo   aooqq aoooq'

# Create a dictionary where the key is the string, value is the number of 'o's
counts = {k: k.count('o')for k in a.split()}
# Calculate the highest count, and return a list of all items whose value equals the count:
[k for m in [max(counts.values())] for k, v in counts.items() if v == m]
# ['aaaooo', 'aoooq']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I propose you:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import re

def get_most_ooo_word(words):

    words = ' '.join(words) # join all the strings into a single string
    words = re.sub(' +', ' ', words) # replace multiple spaces by a single one
    words = words.split(' ') # split the string to obtain all the words

    # initialize an array containing the count of o occurrences for each string
    count = [None] * len(words) 

    # fill it properly using a differentiation
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        count[i] = len(word) - len(word.replace('o',''))

    # find the maximum number of o occurrences
    count_max = max(count)

    # return all the words whose number of o occurrences equals the maximum
    return itemgetter(*[i for i, elem in enumerate(count) if elem == count_max])(words)
```

And here is a small example:

```
print(get_most_ooo_word(['oaa oa ooo', 'aaaa ao oa aaaoooa aooqq aoooqa']))
# ['ooo', 'aaaoooa', 'aoooqa']
```

Answer (score 0):

While you already have your answer, I'd thought to put my two cents in using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

sentence = "This is sooome sentence with oo-words in em."

def getWords(string, char):
    words = sorted(string.split(), key = lambda x: x.count(char), reverse = True)
    return list(takewhile(lambda x: char in x, words))

owords = getWords(sentence, 'o')
print(owords)
```

This yields

```
['sooome', 'oo-words']
```